# Simultaneous movement of two graphics with different and changing text

Tags: java, loops, graphics, repaint

The code I wrote is giving somewhat different output than required.

OUTPUT GOT:

1. In upper movement a yellow rectangle moves from left to right in steps. In each step its text changes by 1 (Signal 1, Signal 2, Signal 3 etc.)
2. In lower movement text moves from left to right (at higher speed than yellow rectangle above).
3. Text in both  (above and below it) remains same i.e. if above is "Signal 1", below is also "Signal 1", if above is "Signal 2" then below is also the same "Signal 2". And so on.

OUTPUT REQUIRED:

Every thing should remain except:
1. In lower movement I need text in green rectangle (same as yellow rectangle above).
2. In the lower movement I need text of higher by 2 in loop. In other words,

```
    if above is "Signal 1"  below should be "Signal 3". 
    If above is "Signal 2"  below should be "Signal 4". 
    If above is "Signal 3"  below should be "Signal 5".
    if above is "Signal 4"  below should be "Signal 6". 
    If above is "Signal 5"  below should be "Signal 7". 
    If above is "Signal 6"  below should be "Signal 8".  
    if above is "Signal 7"  below should be "Signal 9".
    if above is "Signal 8"  below should be "Signal 10". 
    If above is "Signal 9"  below should be "Signal 1". 
    If above is "Signal 10" below should be "Signal 2".
```

Being new to programming and java I need help to get the required output. Thanks in anticipation. My complete working code is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphStepTwo implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private VoyageRunnable VoyageRunnable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GraphStepTwo());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Move");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        VoyageRunnable = new VoyageRunnable(drawingPanel, new Voyage());
        new Thread(VoyageRunnable).start();
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        VoyageRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);  
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {//////////////////////////////// 
        private int xPos, yPos, width, height, xPos2, yPos2, width2, height2;

        private Step step; 

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.width = 100;
            this.height = 50;
            this.xPos = 0;
            this.yPos = 50;


            this.width2 = 100;
            this.height2 = 40;
            this.xPos2 = 0;
            this.yPos2 = 150;

            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 200));
        }


        public void setStep(Step step) {
            this.step = step;
            this.xPos += 10;
            this.xPos2 += 35;
            repaint();
        }



        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);

            if (step != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                centerString(g, new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height),
                        step.getSignal(), g.getFont());




                centerString(g, new Rectangle(xPos2 , yPos2 , width2 , height2),
                        step.getSignal(), g.getFont());

            }
        }

        public void centerString(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String s, Font font) {
            FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

            Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
            int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
            int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
            int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
            int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

            int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
            int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
        }
    }

    public class VoyageRunnable implements Runnable {

        private boolean running;

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private Voyage voyage;

        public VoyageRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel, Voyage voyage) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.voyage = voyage;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Step step = voyage.getStep();
                setStep(step);
                sleep(step);
            }
        }

        public void setStep(final Step step) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {   
                    drawingPanel.setStep(step); 
                }
            });
        }


        private void sleep(Step step) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(step.getDelay());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

    public class Voyage {

        private int index;
        private List<Step> steps;

        public Voyage() {
            this.steps = new ArrayList<>();

            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 1", 2000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 2", 1000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 3", 2000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 4", 1000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 5", 2000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 6", 1000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 7", 2000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 8", 1000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 9", 2000L));
            this.steps.add(new Step("Signal 10", 1000L));

            this.index = 0;
        }

        public Step getStep() {
            Step step = steps.get(index);
            index = ++index % steps.size();
            return step;
        }
    }

    public class Step {///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private final String signal;
        private final long delay;

        public Step(String signal, long delay) {
            this.signal = signal;
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        public String getSignal() {
            return signal;
        }

        public long getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework to me. I don't understand this approach of giving students a pile of code they don't understand instead of making them code from scratch. Also, the naming especially "DrawingPanel" is pretty bad. You might be better off studying programming by reading on the internet than with course material like that.

Instead of adding `width2` etc. to DrawingPanel, you are supposed to create two of them; one for each box with text in it.